# How to achieve per-batch-file echo on/off setting?

Tags: batch-file

We have some complex bat files where one calls another, which calls yet another. All of them have a `@echo off` at the top.

For debugging, I would like to selectively turn echo on in some of them. What is the easiest way to do this? Some ideas I have so far:

- Change the setting only in top level files. But this will only work for the few files known to be non-top-level. Otherwise any file can call any other.
- Change it back to previous setting before exiting each bat file. I will need to ensure there is a single point of exit. I will also need to know the setting on entry, which I don't know how to find.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
@if defined talk (echo on) else (echo off)
```

at the top of each file.  Then you can set TALK=True and kick 'em all on at once.

To do this selectively for a specific file, you will need to use, e.g, TALK_XYZ, and you will need to ensure that every batch file sets echo back off before exiting.  This should likely be done by a "GOTO END" from all exit points:

```
...
:END
@echo off
```

Comment: I tired this approach. The problem is that I want to *selectively* turn logging on in some, not all, files. Otherwise the output is HUGE.

Answer (score 1):

Call `echo on` at the beginning of the files you want to turn it on for and their dependencies (and `echo off` at the end if you wish).

Note: You said it's for debugging, so it doesn't have to follow a grand scheme - it just has to produce output for now.

...unless I'm missing something, of course.

---

You could write a quick script to REM out the echo off calls as well. For each file you want to have echo on for, text-search for ".bat" to get the list of dependencies. Then run the REMming script on them and search those for ".bat", rinse-repeat.

---

Another option is if you don't mind seeing all output, just feed all the files through the REMming script. It's a bit easier than recursively seeking dependencies. Then put a big, blatent `ECHO` command at the beginning and end of the section you want to trace. Load the whole output into notepad and search for your bookmark.

---

For reference, if you just run the command ECHO without any parameters, you can see the current echo setting: "ECHO is on|off.".

Comment: This is similar to the second option I mention except that it does not restore to previous setting at end, so the echo is off when control goes back to the caller. That does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help lc, it seems I am going to have to echo off everywhere.